# Open Option menu on device without hardware keys

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-menu, android-optionsmenu

In my app I want to use an activity without titelbar or actionbar. I solved this with:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.cilenco.lockscreen.Position"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_position" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="com.cilenco.lockscreen.Position" /> 
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

My problem now is that I have to use an option menu and if I run my app on a device without hardware keys I can not open the option menu. I thought I will the Button with 3 dots (Overflow menu) in the bar where the back and home key is but it is not visible. What can I do to open the option menu on devices without hardware keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function `openOptionsMenu()` that you could call
manually in your activity when you want to open the menu.

```
public void openMenu()
{
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```

***Better:***
if you **want the 3 dot overflow button** in the navigation bar
just create your optionsMenu as usual:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    //add your menu
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    //select what happens when you click at an item

    return true;
}
```

and **make sure** to set **both** `minSdkVersion` **and** `targetSdkVersion` to `"10"` or ***lower***!
For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="your.package.name">
    <uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="4" android:targetsdkversion="10" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Great thank you! The targetSdkVersion was the problem. Thanks for that.

Comment: @bricklore what's the way to programaticalkly open OptionsMenu when minSdkVersion is 16. Looks like openOptionsMenu won't work if minSdkVersion is greater than 8